# Centering unknown width object in an unknown width container

Tags: javascript, html, css, centering

I have a styling issue where I'm trying to center a wide image relative to it's container. The problem is that the image's width is unknown so I can't do the `left:50%, margin-left:-###px;` trick because I don't know what the negative margin value will be.

I also can't use `text-align:center;` because the the image is wider than it's container.

To make matters more complicated, the container's width is also unknown.

[image]

I'd quite like to avoid using JavaScript for this but it feels like a big ask with just `CSS`.

Anyone know of any magical solution here?

**UPDATE:**

Required support: IE8+, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Android.

I have tried a couple of the examples provided by you lovely people which have not worked (they would work in most situations, but not mine).

@Vince - I tried your display block trick which works great when the window is wider than the image but when the window is not wider than the image, it effectively becomes 'left-aligned'.

See fiddle example. I have added another container to simulate a narrow mobile device window. Obviously this won't be a hard-coded width as in the fiddle. Also, the img width will not be hard-coded as in the example but I'm trying to simulate the situation that's presented to me.

http://jsfiddle.net/7n1bhzps/1/

Excuse the hideous colours.

**UPDATE 2:**

Accepted dfsq's answer. Contrary to above, it does not need to support IE8 because the problem is at mobile resolutions. IE8 is not a mobile browser so the need to support this is not necessary.

Thanks all.

Comment: What browser support do you need? Can you use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)?

Comment: you can make the image maximum width of 100% and center it. `image {max-width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}`

Comment: Do you know the container width?

Comment: try adding `text-align:center` to parent as `image` is `inline-block` it will `align` `center` and add max-width min-width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of CSS `transofrm: translateX(-50%)` to shift the image of unknown width. This technic allows to center image of any width relative to container.

```css
.wrap {
    margin: 0 0 10px 160px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 75px;
    border: 3px red solid;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap:hover {
    overflow: inherit;
}
.wrap img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/600/75/food/3" alt="">
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/75/food/4" alt="">
</div>
```

Check for support http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d

Comment: Thanks dfsq, unfortunately I need the support IE8. Can you think of an adequate fallback?

Comment: For IE8 I would cancel position: absolute for image and add text-align: center on parent container (using hacks of conditional stylesheet). So the small images would be centered and wide will stick to the left. Good enough for IE8.

Comment: What am I talking about? This is only needed for the mobile resolutions. IE8 is not a mobile browser so I don't even have to worry about supporting it at this resolution. Thanks dfsq!

Answer (score 2):

Set the container's min-width to any value you feel necessary. Set the image to display as block and use the `margin: 0 auto;` trick to center it

HTML:

```
<div id="contain">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/xs8vh.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#contain {
    min-width: 50px;
}
#contain img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j21a8ubo/

Comment: Why do you need to set min-width?

Comment: `margin: 0 auto;` requires the containing element to have a static width set, whether it be `min-width`, `max-width` or `width`. As the asker does not know what the width is of the container, the safest way to center the image (imo) is to use `min-width: 1px;` without affecting any other elements

Comment: Thanks Vince, I gave this a go but had a problem. See question update.

Comment: Sadly this is default browser behavior as far as 'centering' an element that breaks through its boundaries. I'd need to see your code on a real-life use-case to help you any further

Answer (score 0):

If you set X's CSS to `margin:0px auto;` it should center it within the parent container.

Comment: Really? Why wouldn't it? Once it's rendered the width is known enough for `auto` to do its work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this doesn't work with my situation. See question update for more details.

Comment: Does the image need to overflow the container if it's wider than it?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes centering doesn't work, but this can also be a browser-related issue.

If you can adjust the HTML, you could put the element to be centered in a cell in a `<table>` element, with a cell on either side of it. This is how it was done in IE8 and earlier, though it's not recommended now.

Answer (score 0):

If unknown width of object and its container then use

```
.center-block{
    display: table;
    margin:0 auto;
    float:none;   
}
```